# Current Location is Nil In SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, location, latitude-longitude, cllocationmanager

I am getting user's **current location** in my SwiftUI app. To get the **latitude and longitude**, I am using following code **onAppear()** of my view:

```
        let locManager = CLLocationManager()
        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        var currentLocation: CLLocation?

        switch locManager.authorizationStatus {
            
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            print("lat long will nil")
       
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        
            let lati = currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude
            let long = currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude
                
                print("lat: \(lati) long: \(long)")

        @unknown default:
            print("error getting location")
        }
```

And this is printing:

> lat: nil long: nil

I am not getting why is it not getting the current location. My **info.plist** is:

[image: info.plist]

Does anyone knows what's the issue?

Comment: `currentLocation` variable is not initialized.

Comment: So what part of you code is supposed to try to get the location? Getting location has nothing to do with SwiftUI, SwiftUI is cosmetic.

Comment: @loremipsum I just want latitude and longitude of my current location and it is giving nil

Comment: You haven't written any code that actually requests a location from a CLLocationManager. You just declared a variable of type CLLocation? and that's nil. And then later you expect it to be not nil.  See https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-request-user-location/

Comment: You haven't asked for it or even given it a value

Comment: @Shadowrun I requested the location of the user and on my simulator it is "While using the app". I know that first you have to request the user location. The lat and long are still coming nil while the user gives access to the location

Comment: You are requesting permission not the location that is a different method where you have to wait for the delegate to return the location. You request it the same way as in UIKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my question and it is that you have to just add **one** line in **case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:**

> currentLocation = locManager.location

The whole code will:

```
        let locManager = CLLocationManager()
        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        var currentLocation: CLLocation?

        switch locManager.authorizationStatus {
            
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            print("lat long will nil")
       
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        
            currentLocation = locManager.location

            let lati = currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude
            let long = currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude
                
                print("lat: \(lati) long: \(long)")

        @unknown default:
            print("error getting location")
        }
```

Comment: You are confusing requesting "location permission" and "requesting a location".  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation

Comment: The instance property "currentLocation" on CLLocationManager may or may not have a value. If it does, it may not be very recent.  You're relying on other system services and other apps to have requested location recently.  You should, if you want the determine the user's location now (rather than whatever the last known value was, no matter how old), set the delegate, and call requestLocation if/when you have permission.

Comment: @Shadowrun my question is for the latitude and longitude are nil, I didn't ask for the location permission. I want to get my current latitude and longitude and this is the code to get the current lat and long, I am not asking for any permissions here

Comment: What does "locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()"  do?